# Forzar la descarga de un fichero csv desde un servlet

Tags: java, csv, response

Estoy realizando una aplicación en java donde hay que descargar un fichero CSV. 
Pero me está ocurriendo que el navegador no muestra el dialogo de descarga, sino que lo muestra incrustado en el propio navegador.

Este es el código de mi servlet:

```
        List<MisDatosBean> listaDatos = miDAL.obtenerDatos();
        if (listaDatos!= null) {
            PrintWriter writer;
            writer = response.getWriter();
            for (MisDatosBean d : listaDatos) {
                CSVUtils.writeLine(writer, generarLista(d));
            }
            response.setContentType("text/csv");
            response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"datos.csv\"");
            if (!request.isSecure()) {
                response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
                response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
                response.setHeader("Expires", "0");
            }
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
        }
```

¿Qué más hay que indicar, para que me muestre el diálogo de descarga? Me ocurre en todos los navegadores que he probado, tanto IE11, firefox y chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al fin, mediante esta [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6520231/how-to-force-browser-to-download-file) he podido solucionarlo.

El caso es que la descripción de la cabecera hay que hacerla antes de escribir el contenido del archivo en el flujo de salida.

Es decir, quedaría asi:

```
        List<MisDatosBean> listaDatos = miDAL.obtenerDatos();
    if (listaDatos!= null) {
        response.setContentType("text/csv");
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"datos.csv\"");
        if (!request.isSecure()) {
            response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
            response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
            response.setHeader("Expires", "0");
        }
        PrintWriter writer;
        writer = response.getWriter();
        for (MisDatosBean d : listaDatos) {
            CSVUtils.writeLine(writer, generarLista(d));
        }
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
    }
```

Al hacerlo así, el navegador ya da la opción de descargarlo en lugar de mostrarlo.